# Not cycling through an array as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the `player` to continue on after he jumps (see code), but what he does is return back to the `jumpPosition` transform without continuing on to the next point.

Here is what it is doing in Unity:

[image]
 ...

Here is my code for `playerMovment`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{

    // public GameObject playerToMove;           // not sure why I need this 

    public float moveSpeed;                     // move speed of the player going from player postion to current point, possible to use somewhere else

    private Transform currentPoint;             // used to determine where the next point the player has to move by cycling through 'points' array
    public Transform jumpPoint;                 // used as a location trigger to tell the player when to jump -- will be attempting to make into an array
    public Transform crouchPoint;               // used as a location trigger to tell the player when to crounch -- will be attempting to make into an array
    public Transform[] points;                  // an array of location for the 'currentPoint' to cycle through 

    public float maxPause = 100;                // used to determine the length of time between when the player arrives at the 'currentPoint' and when to leave said point; default = 100
    public float reducedPause = 2;                // used to set 'maxPause' to a smaller number so that player won't keep jumping/crouching

    public TestCharacterController2D controller; // acceses the TestCharacterController2D script (I didnt write this script but plan to modiify) used for basic move, jump, and crouch funtions 

    public Animator animator;                   // my attempt to find the player's animator

    public bool isRight;                        // used to to determine which way the character is facing -- I think this can be accesed through the 'controller' variable (TestCharacterController2D script)

    private bool jump;                          // to tell the 'controller' when to jump
    private bool crouch;                        // to tell the 'controller' when to crouch
    private bool pause = false;                 // used to determine when the player arrives at the 'currentPoint' and the 'maxPause' countdown begins

    public int pointsSelection;                 // used to cycle the 'points' array when maxPause cycle is over and player is at current point

    //   public float jumpHeight = 100f;             // not sure why used


    void Start()                                         // looking into 'onAwake' maybe? (or others)
    {
        currentPoint = points[pointsSelection];         // sets currentPoint to default location ('pointSelection' is 'publc' so can be modified in Unity


        isRight = true;                                 // player starts facing right -- as per character animations

    }

    void Update() // not sure if should have more in 'FixedUpdate' or others (maybe?)
    {
        jump = false;

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, currentPoint.position) < 0.05f)
        // checks to see if player is at 'currentPoint' 
        {
            pause = true; // starts the pause sequenece
            Debug.Log("Pause = " + pause);

            if (pause) // when the movement is pause do the the following
            {
                moveSpeed = 0;

                animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0); // player stops moving -- works!

                if (maxPause <= 100) // checks to see if still paused
                {

                    Debug.Log("this is maxPause: " + maxPause);

                    if (maxPause < 0) // found 'maxPause' was going to far below zero
                        maxPause = 0;

                    maxPause--; // reduce pause amount (working way out of loop)

                }



                if (maxPause == 0) // when 'maxPause' timer has finished
                {
                    pointsSelection++; // move to next point
                    maxPause = 100; // reset 'maxPause' timer
                    pause = false; // resume 'transform.position == currentPoint.position' process
                }

            }


            if (pointsSelection == points.Length) // makes sure 'pointsSelection' doesn't go out of bounds
            {
                Debug.Log("at end of array");
                pointsSelection = 0; // start the player's movement process over again
            }

        }
        else // not sure if requried
        {
            Debug.Log("pause = false");
            Debug.Log("this is the moveSpeed " + moveSpeed);
            Debug.Log("pointsSelection: " + pointsSelection);
        }

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, jumpPoint.position) < 0.05f && jumpPoint == currentPoint) // conditions for the jump action (automatic) -- I fell the whole thing needs to be more elaborate ** WORK IN PROGRESS **
        {
            jump = true;
        }
        else
            jump = false;

        currentPoint = points[pointsSelection]; // moved to line 130 -- not sure if better here


    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (isRight && transform.position.x > currentPoint.position.x) // flipping the character -- I'm pretty sure I can use TestCharacterController2D to do this for me, this is comparing the player's 'transform' 
        {
            moveSpeed = -0.25f; // tells controller to head in the left direction
            isRight = false;   // no longer facing right 
        }
        if (!isRight && transform.position.x < currentPoint.position.x) // reverse of above
        {
            moveSpeed = 0.25f; // tells controller to head in the right direction
            isRight = true; // no longer facing left
        }

        if (moveSpeed > 0 || moveSpeed < 0)
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", 1); // player starts PlayerRun animation -- works!


        // Move our character
        controller.Move(moveSpeed, crouch, jump); // draws from the TestCharacterController2D script

    }


    public void OnLanding()
    {
        animator.SetBool("Jumped", false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Side convo: Every line in the code does *not* need a comment. If you find yourself needing a comment, maybe think of ways to write more descriptive *code.*

Comment: wasn't sure how far to go when commenting lol...I'm new to this

Comment: In your spare time, maybe give Robert C. Martin's Clean Code a read.  https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0132350882/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_4bRmCb2CF17WM

Comment: thanks for the tip always looking for was to improve my coding

Comment: I don’t mind the comments.  I’d rather have more comments than less comments.  And if you are just working off the cuff, and not off any formal requirements, it’s always helpful to look back and know why you did something.  Knowing what the code is doing and why it’s doing are two different things.  I’ve never rejected a pull request for too many comments.

Comment: Now back to the question  :- )  I don't have the stamina to go through all your code so instead a tip that is hopefully useful: I see you have discovered logging (`Debug.Log`) and I suggest you use it to track down the x movement that alludes you. Sprinkle with logging of the x position and read and read to figure out where x was reset.

Comment: Thanks for the type...the debugging is going a little better now !!